# Use of Nagara if two people are involved

Tags: particles

Can you still use *nagara* if two people are doing the actions? For example

> I was reading while he was making dinner.

Comment: Just precise the subject in the proposition where it's the most significant, or in both parts of the sentence : "kare ga shokuji shinagara, boku ga yonde ita".

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3050/9831

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar (Seiichi Makino and Michio Tsutsui):

> nagara cannot be used when the subjects of the two actions are different. In this case aida is used.

Here's my attempt at your sentence:

> 彼{かれ}が夕食{ゆうしょく}を作{つく}っている間{あいだ}、私は[本]{ほん}を読{よ}んでいた。(or [読書]{どくしょ}をしていた。)
>   kare ga yuushoku o tsukutteiru aida, watashi wa hon o yondeita. (dokusho o shiteita.)

Comment: shouldn't aida be followed by the particle "ni" usually?

Comment: That depends on whether you read for the whole time that he was cooking. You can add に but it will change the meaning slightly. It will mean that you read for some of the time (but not necessarily the whole time) that he was cooking.

Comment: Although it doesn't impact the main point, should "making" perhaps be "作る" here (as in "作る間")? I'm admittedly not a native speaker, but 作る feels like a case where the -ている form might indicate completion, rather than the present progressive.

Comment: @EthanKaminski 「作っている間」で自然だと思いますが・・。「彼が夕食を作っている間、私は～～していました」の「作っている」は、 completion ではなく progressive でいいと思います

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks for the correction. I hadn't realised that using 読む without the object/context was unnatural.